# Why Can Monotonic Convergence Be Used Here?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

a. In the second equality, why can we use the monotone convergence? is $1_{(x:f(x)\geq n)}$ is an increasing function?

b. In the third equality what function is $n_{(x:n+1>f(x)\geq n)}$ ?

Comment: If $n$ gets bigger that function for sure gets smaller. I assume $n = n\cdot 1$?

Comment: (a) The terms are all nonnegative, so the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N} 1_{\{x : f(x) \geq n\}}$ are pointwise increasing as a function of $N$, hence the monotone convergence theorem applies. (b) Probably should be $n \cdot 1_{\{x : n+1 > f(x) \geq n\}}$.

Comment: Monotone convergence is used on $\sum_{n=1}^N 1_{\{x : f(x) \geq n\}},$ not on the indicator function itself.  (The corresponding theorem you would be applying to $1_{\{x : f(x) \geq n\}}$ is Tonelli's theorem)